# UITableView add border also add borders on HeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I add border to my UITableView(using *CALayer*), it also adds border to the `UITableView.tableHeaderView`
But I need border only around the table not header.

Since I have only one section in my table, so I tried customizing header view by

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

But still it doesn't work.

How can I set border of only the tableView not the header view?

I know one possible solution - make a view (for border) and add it to table view, but I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: No it does not works.It just changes the color of the separating lines between row of tableView.

Comment: @newbee is right, that indeed not correct what you're saying. Have you found a solution by now, @newbee?

Comment: @WouterDS There is no direct way of doing it so I added separate header view instead of using viewForHeaderInSection.It solved 2 issues for me- 1.Border issue 2.Stop table header bouncing with the table.

Comment: @Sandy: I've fixed it with CALayers. Draw a border myself (did this in viewForHeaderInSection).